# stop javascript executing when catch error

Tags: javascript

I need a function that stop execute javascript when catch error. For example as follow:

```
function AA()
{
  try{
    executeScript();
  }catch(e){
    //stop execute javascript
  }
}

function executeScript()
{
   throw 'error';
}
function BB()
{
  //some script
}
AA();
BB(); //don't execute when error happening
```

Has anybody know how to do it? Thanks for help.

Comment: If these answers doesn't satisfy your needs, could you please add more information...

Answer (score 8):

I think if you use a return it should be possible :)

```
function AA()
{
  try{
  }catch(e){
    //stop execute javascript
    return;
  }
  BB(); //don't execute when error happening
}

function BB()
{
  //some script
}
```

**return** like that will just return **undefined**. You can return something more specific like a string or anything else to be able to have a convenient behaviour when you get this early return.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways,

1. Add return statement

   ```
    function AA()
    {
      try{
      }catch(e){
        return;
      }
      BB();  
    }

    function BB(){   
    }
   ```
2. If you want to return from in code before catch calls you can add throw

   ```
   function AA() {           
       try{
          javascript_abort();
        }catch(e){
           return;
        }
        BB();  
       }


    function BB(){   
            }

        function javascript_abort(){
           throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');
        }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use setTimeout if you want code from AA to be redundantly to be executed.

```
function AA()
{
  try{

  }catch(e){
    return;
  }
  BB(); //don't execute when error happening
  setTimeout("AA()",500);
}

function BB()
{
  //some script
}
```

Comment: sometimes you need some code to be executed until an event is triggered.

Comment: I really don't see what that has to do with the code you posted -- or what that has to do with the question =/