# How to quit from a function after getting an error in the loop?

Tags: javascript

What `return` does is sending me to the beginning of the function. However it is useless for me. I am running the function every 30 seconds with an Interval. So it keeps running where I need it to run every 30 seconds for once.

And as far as I know `break` isn't helping either, it is breaking the loop but still processing the rest of codes.

So is there a function or code where it kills function totally until I recall it?

Thanks for your time!

Edit: After requets.

Edit 2: To be clear, stopping an Interval isn't what I need.

So here is an example of mine. What I need on this code is checking for error every 15 second. But what does this code is checking error and if it gets error it is checking again.

```js
        setInterval(checkError, 15000);
        
        function checkError() {
    if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
        }
```

Comment: [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: Alright, just posted the code

Comment: Also see [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: Stopping interval isn't what I need, I need to stop function after getting an error. Until I recall it.

Comment: u can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220665/stop-javascript-executing-when-catch-error

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement never takes you to the beginning of the function. What happens here is that you don't stop the `setInterval` function calling your `checkError` function again.

Please use `clearInterval` to stop the recurring of this whenever you want - in this case when an error is found.

```
var interval = setInterval(checkError, 15000);

function checkError() {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      clearInterval(interval);   //Stop the recurring here
   }
}
```